# Unable to capture unload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Ultimately, my goal is to clear localStorage if the user closes the browser or navigates to another page (not if they refresh the current page).  I am just trying right now to capture the unload event using "beforeunload", but I cannot get it to fire.

```
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Bye');
    
});
```

Comment: well you can not prevent it so that line is not going to do anything.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using sessionStorage? Seems like you are recreating the wheel.

Comment: Browsers will not show alerts, prompts, confirms in the method. So if you think not seeing the alert means it is not working, it is working as intended. Call your method to remove the local storage, open page back up and verify it is gone.

Comment: @epascarello - I am using localStorage to save the current selected tab.  I actually want to clear that item when the user leaves the page or closes the browser.

Comment: So sounds like a perfect solution for sessionStorage. But your code would work if you set it to clear the storage in it. The browser is not going to show the alert.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
...
}
```

does this work? Also as was commented this event us unpreventable